# Can't save data in hook_node_update()

Tags: hooks, entities, nodes

I have a node type with two field_collection fields. When I save the node I need to write the entity_id of the first field_collection into the secondo field_collection. This is my code:

```
function mymodule_node_update($node){
    $entity_id = $node->field_collection_1['und'][0]['value'];
    $entiry_array = entity_load('field_collection_item',array(entity_id));
    $entity = array_shift($entity_array);

    if (empty($entity->field_reference['und'][0]['value'])) {
        $entity->field_reference['und'][0]['value'] = $node->field_collection_2['und'][0]['value'];
        $entity->save();
    }
}
```

There are 2 problems there: 
1) in hook_node_update() data is not committed yet https://drupal.org/node/1677830
2) $entity->save() triggers again hook_node_update() (and in my opinion it shouldn't)

So at the end in $node->field_collection_1 I have the right id $node->field_collection_2 would have, but due to recursive call to hook_node_update() and the fact that in hook_node_update() data is not committed to database yet field_collection_2 entity and all changes made to the node vanish.

Can someone suggest me a possible solution?

Thank you

Comment: One thing to keep in mind if you choose to use `hook_node_update()`: That hook is called for ALL node types, so it's wise to check the $node->type.

Comment: Yes sure, I removed all the unnecessary code to focus the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[hook_node_presave($node)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

> Act on a node being inserted or updated.
>
> This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the
>   database.
>   Parameters
>
> $node: The node that is being inserted or updated.

```
function hook_node_presave($node) {

if ($node->type == 'your_node_type') {
// you can write your desired code here


}

}
```

Comment: Just to add a word of clarification: the code should simply update the fields in the node object at this point, not save anything to the database. Drupal will do the database updates for you.

Comment: am i wrong somewhere can u pls explain ?

Comment: No, using presave is correct. But what the OP asked requires changes to some fields which are part of the node: they should be able to do that simply by altering the node object in this hook; they don't need to perform any DB updates themselves.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here, nor what relevance it has to the original question, sorry. Perhaps you should raise a question of your own where you explain more fully.

Comment: I'm not sure node_hook_presave() is the solution. During this hook the node still transient so I don't have the field_collection_2 entity_id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee that everything including access rights is written to the database, you can register a shutdown function in one of the node hooks. You do that with drupal_register_shutdown_function passing in an arbitrary function name and the arguments. Here's how it might look for your case in hook_node_update:

```
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  // only register shutdown for node of the right type
  // let's assume the node content type is 'foobar'
  if ($node->type == 'foobar') {
    drupal_register_shutdown_function('node_voodoo_on_shutdown', $node);
  }
}

function node_voodoo_on_shutdown($node) {
    $entity_id = $node->field_collection_1['und'][0]['value'];
    $entity = entity_load_single('field_collection_item',entity_id);

    if (empty($entity->field_reference['und'][0]['value'])) {
        $entity->field_reference['und'][0]['value'] = $node->field_collection_2['und'][0]['value'];
        $entity->save();
    }
}
```